# Creating query criteria for finding documents has desired element inside of array of array in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am implementing an application with Spring boot and using MongoDB as database for the first time.

I need to create a criteria for a query for MongoDB, however I do not know how to do. My document looks like this:

```
...
"mylists" : [
               {
                    "subListName" : "Main",
                    "list" : [
                            {
                                    "name" : "abc",
                                    "amount" : "3"
                            },
                            {
                                    "name" : "adf",
                                    "amount" : "1"
                            },
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "subListName" : "Additional1",
                    "list" : [
                            {
                                    "name" : "xyz",
                                    "amount" : "1"
                            }, 
                            {
                                    "name" : "dbr",
                                    "amount" : "1"
                            }
                    ]
            }
        ],
...
```

I want to get documents where it has 'abc' in its one of lists. As you can see, mylists array contains 1 or more subList and each subList contains again 1 or more object.

For a regular 1d array, I am able to create a query like this:

`criteria.add(Criteria.where("list").in('abc'), "i"));`

My lists are in also another big list. Also abc is in a field of 'name'. So I could not figure out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoDB's [official driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/) and it's straightforward.  I use v. 3.8.2.  Because you only match one field, you can use either `$elemMatch` or simply find directly.  Here are examples.

```
collection.find(elemMatch("mylists.list", eq("name", "abc")))
```

or

```
collection.find(eq("mylists.list.name", "abc"))
```

For more info, take a look at the [Find Operations tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/).